# Tying geom_smooth to a specific model

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have the following dataset

```
x = rnorm(1000)
a = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size=length(x), replace=T)
X = model.matrix(~a*x)
y = as.vector( X %*% c(0, .3, .5, .3, -.3, .1) ) + rnorm(length(x), 0, .2)
data = data.frame(y,a,x)
```

Now let's say I model a main effects only model

```
mod = lm(y~a+x, data=data)
```

If I wanted to visualize the fit of this model, I could use ggplot2:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(~a) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

The problem is that the displayed lines do not match the model. (The graphed lines have interactions, but the model does not).

The appropriate way to model this would require a few steps: first, create new columns that contain the intercepts for each group:

```
data$intercepts = 0; 
  data$intercepts[data$a=="B"] = coef(mod)[2]
  data$intercepts[data$a=="C"] = coef(mod)[3]
```

Then plot the separate lines for each model like this:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(~a) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = intercepts, slope = coef(mod)[4]))
```

This works great for this once instance. But I'm trying to make a function that is more general and can accommodate any sort of model/visual.

Is there a way to supply the fitted model to ggplot and have it work its magic?

In the past, I've used the `predict` function to "hack" ggplot into making the model I want (i.e., by making a grid of predictor values, computing the predictions, then using geom_line to "connect the dots.") For this specific application, that will not work. Instead, I need to specify the slope/intercept by panel, but need the function to be smart enough to recognize when there are interactions/main effects/three-way interactions.

My first thought was to use the `model.matrix` to generate predictions within each panel of the fitted object. The advantage of `model.matrix` is I don't have to figure out whether there are interactions/main effects/polynomials, etc.... But I'm not having any success with that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

Simply calculate the points that you want (i.e. the fitted values), then use `geom_line` to plot them:

```r
data$pred <- predict(mod)
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes(y = pred)) + 
  facet_grid(~a)
```

[image]

**Rationale**

I've found that it's usually easier to just add the data to the original data object that you input. In this case, just use `predict(mod)` to find the fitted values, and you're done. We store them as `data$pred`, and then we call `geom_line` with `aes(y = pred)` to actually draw them.

Note that this solution generalizes to any model. Here's an example where I modified your data generation to include a quadratic term, created an `lm` call with a quadratic term, and called the exact same `ggplot` code.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@slamballais's answer is good. A slightly more streamlined version:

```r
aa <- broom::augment(mod, interval="confidence")
gg_pred <- (gg 
    + geom_line(data=aa, aes(y=.fitted), colour="blue")
    + geom_ribbon(data=aa, aes(ymin=.lower, ymax=.upper), colour=NA, alpha=0.3)
)
print(gg_pred)
```

This gets a little trickier if you want e.g. evenly spaced points (and not too many) for predicting a nonlinear fit. See also the `ggeffects` package (especially `ggpredict`) and the `sjPlot` package.